# Callonce in background is being called multiple times rather than just once

Tags: karate

We recently noticed that a callonce function in the background was not necessarily called once per feature, as shown in the below image.  Has anyone else experienced this?

You can see from the image that the `adapters.splitAuthentication` ran successfully in the first scenario, but was then called again in the second scenario where it failed.
[image: callonce ran more than once]

Comment: this approach should work for callonce and not just callSingle - else no other suggestions: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/commit/329aa69b3325dcbc0e54bf8f5e0d774689a837a4

Comment: Understood, but as shown in the image, it did not work while using callonce